# Using the grep command or another command for subsetting

Tags: r, subset

I'm using the latest 5 years of apple and google using the quant mode command

```
loadSymbols(c("AAPL", "GOOG"))
AAPL['2016::']
```

This is the dataset I have.

```
AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2016-01-04   25.6525   26.3425  25.5000    26.3375   270597600      24.36454
2016-01-05   26.4375   26.4625  25.6025    25.6775   223164000      23.75398
2016-01-06   25.1400   25.5925  24.9675    25.1750   273829600      23.28912
2016-01-07   24.6700   25.0325  24.1075    24.1125   324377600      22.30621
2016-01-08   24.6375   24.7775  24.1900    24.2400   283192000      22.42415
```

It continues for everyday up till 2020. I want to just get the data of AAPL volume for every 1st day of every month. So for a year, there will be 12 data, which is 1st of every month. And I need it for 5 years.

Using previous threads, I was hoping to use the grep command, but any other command would be very helpful.

Comment: see my answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089610/choosing-only-a-monthly-subset-using-quantmod/66089734?noredirect=1#comment116848268_66089734

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep` with the pattern to match 4 digits followed by `-`, then 2 digits, `-` and the '01' at the end in the `index` of the dataset to subset the rows

```
out <- df[grep("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-01", index(df)),]
```

-output

```
head(out)
#           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
#2016-02-01   24.1175   24.1775  23.8500    24.1075   163774000      22.30158
#2016-03-01   24.4125   25.1925  24.3550    25.1325   201628400      23.37596
#2016-04-01   27.1950   27.5000  27.0500    27.4975   103496000      25.57567
#2016-06-01   24.7550   24.8850  24.5825    24.6150   116693200      23.03402
#2016-07-01   23.8725   24.1175  23.8325    23.9725   104106000      22.43279
#2016-08-01   26.1025   26.5375  26.1025    26.5125   152671600      24.80965
```

#### data

```
df <- AAPL['2016::']
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didnt. 
This is what I get

AAPL[grep("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-01", rownames(AAPL)),]
     AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted

Comment: @ShaneMurphy just change it to `index` from `row.names`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your dataframe is called `df`, this should give you the `AAPL.Volume`value for each first day of month:

```
df$AAPL.Volume[grepl("01$", df$AAPL.Open)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and looking for a date of `"01"` will return data for those months where there *is* a `-01` date; if there is any hole in the data, the month will be skipped. If that's not desired, then here's a way to grab the *first* row of each year/month group:

```r
dat[!duplicated(gsub("-[0-9]{2}$", "", rownames(dat))),]
#            AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2016-01-04   25.6525   26.3425     25.5    26.3375   270597600      24.36454
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tibble)
dat %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  group_by(yearmon = gsub("-[0-9]{2}$", "", rowname)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 1 x 8
#   rowname    AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted yearmon
#   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <int>         <dbl> <chr>  
# 1 2016-01-04      25.7      26.3     25.5       26.3   270597600          24.4 2016-01
```